# file limit in dos emulators

Tags: emulation, dosbox

I'm currently trying to run a dos console application which has to open a certain number of files simultaneously ( more than 15 ). I've tried with dosbox and dosemu. Dosbox is supposed to support 127 simultaneous files, and dosemu has the config.sys file in which you can set this limit. So I tried a little C program that opens files and i got this results:

```
int main (void) {

  FILE *archivos[300];
  char numstr[15];
  int i=0,nmax=0;

  printf("\nIngrese el numero maximo de archivos que desea crear: ");
  scanf("%d",&nmax);
  for( i=0; i<nmax ; i++) { 
    sprintf( numstr, "prueba%d.dat", i);
    if(!(archivos[i]=fopen( numstr ,"w"))) 
    {
      printf("\nNo se pudo abrir el archivo %s", numstr);
      printf("\nEl numero maximo de archivos abiertos fue: %d", i);
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  printf("\nNo ocurrio un error. El numero de archivos abiertos es: %d\n", i);
  for( i=0; i<nmax; i++)
    fclose( archivos[i] ); 
  return( 0 );
}
```

Both dosemu and dosbox let me open 15 files only.

this is config.sys from dosemu (where files=100):

```
rem config.sys for DOSEMU + FreeDOS
rem note that the initial "D:" is set to "Z:" at the end
SWITCHES=/F
DOS=UMB,HIGH
dosdata=umb
lastdrive=Z
files=100
stacks=0
buffers=10
device=d:\dosemu\ems.sys
devicehigh=d:\dosemu\cdrom.sys 
install=d:\dosemu\lredir.com z: linux\fs\${DOSEMU_LIB_DIR}/drive_z ro
shellhigh=z:\command.com /e:1024 /p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after doing some research, I've found that even if you set the file limit in dosbox or dosemu, this will affect to the number of files you can open per terminal. The number of files you can open from a single process it has to do with the number of available file handles, in this case 20 for msdos systems, 5 for stderr, stdin, stdout, stdaux, sdtprn. As explains this  [MS-DOS programmer FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/msdos-programmer-faq/part3/section-12.html).